# Can't find toChannelCredentials() in C# for Google API Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, google-authentication, google-vision

On this page, https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production, there is a guide with examples on how to set up google API authentication. However, my IDE doesn't seem to understand or be able to find the "ToChannelCredentials()" method needed for verification. Is there something specific I haven't imported? Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Grpc.Core;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("myPath").CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.;
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var image = Image.FromFile("myImage");
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add:

using Grpc.Auth;

And you'll need to reference Google.Apis.Core.